# Создание круга, поделенного на сектора с сегментами

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Мне нужно нарисовать вот такой вот элемент в WPF. Каждому сегменту я должен иметь возможность указать его уникальный цвет. Также требуется, чтобы этот элемент занимал все доступное ему место. В голову приходят варианты только с полным описанием всей логики отрисовки в Code-Behind или созданием собственной панели (но это еще сложнее выйдет). Может это как-нибудь можно в xaml описать?
[image: круг]

Comment: А сам элемент статичен? Т.е. кол-во сегментов, их положение, относительный размер, на сектора не изменяются?

Comment: Вопрос скорее в семантике. Вам нужно просто «нарисовать» это (тогда смотрите в сторону `CombinedGeometry`), или отдельные элементы должны быть активными и иметь собственную логику реакции на события?

Comment: @AlexeyGrebenyukov Количество секторов с сегментами не меняется. Изменяться может только их размер, если пользователь будет менять размер экрана.

Comment: @VladD Может поменяться фон самих сегментов и стрелка в виде треугольника вне круга может менять положение при смене входных данных.

Comment: Тут возможно должна быть картинка после "вот этот элемент". Но я ее ее вижу. Могу предположить, что вы работаете с `Path`. В этом случае у него есть свойство, отвечающее за Stretch геометрии. Типа вы можете нарисовать квадрат 0,0 1,0 1,1 0,1 и сказать ему растянуться по всему Path с сохранением пропорций или без сохранения пропорций.

Comment: @iRumba Странно, что вы картинку не видите. Не знал, что у Path есть такое свойство. Щас подумаю над этим.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.stretch(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @VlaD Может сможешь подсказать как мне быть. Я последний сегмент, где пишется номер сегмента, хочу сделать в виде TextBlock, ограниченного геометрией. Если я буду крутить сам TextBlock, то понятное дело, что и значение внутри будет крутиться. Если я буду крутить саму геометрию, то я потом не могу ограничить нормально размер TextBlock, что бы число писалось в центре.

Comment: @Nodon: Ну например, можно положить `TextBlock` сверху, и применить к нему `RenderTransform` с центром в центре текста.

Comment: @VladD Я надеялся на более интересное решение :-)

Comment: @Nodon: Изящнее пока не пришло в голову.

Comment: @Nodon: На самом деле, можно отрисовать только один сектор, и получать остальные через `RenderTransform`. И текст вместе с ними.

Comment: @VlaD Я с этим кругом уже смачно голову поломал. Но все решения какие-то в виде костылей выходят. Уж больно много всяких расчетов с синусами и косинусами. Можно еще попробовать конвертеры использовать вместо Code Behind, но опять же не очень таки красиво все выглядит и кода больше писать.

Comment: @VladD У меня сейчас в xaml используется ItemsControl с DataTemplate. Но размер сегментов приходится рассчитывать в Code Behind по событию от ItemsControl. Геометрия сегментов в ресурсах находится.

Comment: @Nodon: Ну размер, допустим, да, а почему синусы и косинусы? По идее, просто выкатывайте Transform, он посчитает косинусы за вас.

Comment: @VladD Тк я сделал работу при помощи списка секторов и ItemsControl, то размер каждого сектора мне нужно пересчитать в зависимости от количества секторов. Для расчета координат PathGeometry мне нужен использовать тригонометрию. Дальше если я буду рисовать TextBox просто поверх всего остального, то мне нужно указать TranslateTransform на сколько пикселей и куда смещать, а это опять расчеты. Мне тут известен только радиус и угол.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну что же, чистого решения на XAML'е у меня не вышло, кое-где пришлось применять тригонометрию. Но почти чистое решение есть.

Начнём с простого случая: размер квадратного поля известен заранее. Пускай он будет 200 × 200.

Для того, чтобы нарисовать кусочек интерфейса, нам нужно немного покопаться в `PathGeometry`. Для первого сегмента пишем нечто вот такое:

```
<Path Fill="Pink"
      Data="M 0,-100 A 100,100 30 0 1 50,-86.602 L 25,-43.301 A 50,50 30 0 0 0,-50 z">
    <Path.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform X="100" Y="100"/>
    </Path.RenderTransform>
</Path>
```

Я вычислял координаты как будто бы центр лежит в начале координат для того, чтобы остальные куски получались аналогично. Мне пришлось, понятно, сдвинуться в центр при помощи трансляции.

[image: первая попытка]

Добавим вторую точно такую же часть, но с другим углом поворота:

```
<Path Fill="Pink"
      Data="M 0,-100 A 100,100 30 0 1 50,-86.602 L 25,-43.301 A 50,50 30 0 0 0,-50 z">
    <Path.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <TranslateTransform X="100" Y="100"/>
            <RotateTransform Angle="0" CenterX="100" CenterY="100"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Path.RenderTransform>
</Path>
<Path Fill="Bisque"
      Data="M 0,-100 A 100,100 30 0 1 50,-86.602 L 25,-43.301 A 50,50 30 0 0 0,-50 z">
    <Path.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <TranslateTransform X="100" Y="100"/>
            <!-- единственное отличие тут -->
            <RotateTransform Angle="30" CenterX="100" CenterY="100"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Path.RenderTransform>
</Path>
```

Результат обнадёживает:

[image: вторая попытка]

Хорошо, теперь попробуем добавить текстовую метку в середину каждого куска. Для начала, мы не хотим заморачиваться с динамическим вычислением размера текста, а хотим центрировать текст относительно данной точки. Но если положить текст в контейнер нулевого размера, то он обрежется границами контейнера. Поэтому сделаем кастомный декоратор, который будет (1) не обрезать контент, (2) центрировать его внутри себя, и (3) обладать нулевым размером.

```
class CenteringNoClipper : Decorator
{
    // не обрезаем контент своими краями
    protected override Geometry GetLayoutClip(Size layoutSlotSize)
    {
        return null;
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        // даём контенту сколько угодно места
        Child.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity, double.PositiveInfinity));
        // а сами занимаем ноль
        return new Size();
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        var childSize = Child.DesiredSize;
        // центрируем контент в том размере, какой он хочет
        Child.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(-childSize.Width/2, -childSize.Height/2),
                               childSize));
        // а сами занимаем ноль места
        return new Size();
    }
}
```

Имея такой декоратор, текстовую метку легко положить там, где нам хочется:

```
<!-- изначально центрируем текст в точке (0, 0) -->
<src:CenteringNoClipper>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Привет"/>
    <!-- переносим куда надо трансформацией -->
    <src:CenteringNoClipper.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <!-- компенсация будущего разворота -->
            <RotateTransform Angle="-15"/>
            <!-- наше расстояние от центра (0, 0) равно 75 -->
            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="-75"/>
            <!-- поворачиваем относительно центра на 15 градусов -->
            <RotateTransform Angle="15"/>
            <!-- переносимся в новый центр, в середине квадрата -->
            <TranslateTransform X="100" Y="100"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </src:CenteringNoClipper.RenderTransform>
</src:CenteringNoClipper>
<src:CenteringNoClipper>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="мир!"/>
    <src:CenteringNoClipper.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <!-- отличие тут -->
            <RotateTransform Angle="-45"/>
            <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="-75"/>
            <!-- и тут -->
            <RotateTransform Angle="45"/>
            <TranslateTransform X="100" Y="100"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </src:CenteringNoClipper.RenderTransform>
</src:CenteringNoClipper>
```

Получаем вот такой результат:

[image: теперь с текстом]

Что осталось сделать? Нужно отойти от заданной ширины в 200 пикселей, и разбросать код по `UserControl`'ам, чтобы избежать дублирования.

Для того, чтобы отойти от ширины, нужно воспользоваться скалированием. Хитрость состоит в том, что нельзя скалировать весь `Path`, потому что в этом случае пропорционально отскалируется и ширина границы. Скалировать нужно только геометрию:

```
<Path Fill="Pink">
    <Path.Data>
        <PathGeometry>
            <PathGeometry.Figures>
                M 0,-1 A 1,1 30 0 1 0.5,-0.86602 L 0.25,-0.43301 A 0.5,0.5 30 0 0 0,-0.5 z
            </PathGeometry.Figures>
            <PathGeometry.Transform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <TranslateTransform X="100" Y="100"/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="0" CenterX="100" CenterY="100"/>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="100" ScaleY="100" CenterX="100" CenterY="100"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </PathGeometry.Transform>
        </PathGeometry>
    </Path.Data>
</Path>
```

Теперь скалирование можно задать через `Binding`.

Следующая проблема — размер области. Нам нужен контрол, который сохраняет aspect ratio. Готового такого нет, но это будет полезная штука, так что засучим рукава и напишем его. (Поскольку контрол полезен сам по себе, я написал его более общим образом.)

```
public class AspectRatioDecorator : Decorator
{
    #region dp double AspectRatio with validator ValidateAspectRatio
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AspectRatioProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "AspectRatio",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(AspectRatioDecorator),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                    1.0,
                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure),
            ValidateAspectRatio);

    public double AspectRatio
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(AspectRatioProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AspectRatioProperty, value); }
    }

    static bool ValidateAspectRatio(object value)
    {
        if (!(value is double))
            return false;

        var aspectRatio = (double)value;
        return aspectRatio > 0 &&
               !double.IsInfinity(aspectRatio) &&
               !double.IsNaN(aspectRatio);
    }
    #endregion

    #region dp HorizontalAlignment HorizontalChildAlignment
    public HorizontalAlignment HorizontalChildAlignment
    {
        get { return (HorizontalAlignment)GetValue(HorizontalChildAlignmentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HorizontalChildAlignmentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HorizontalChildAlignmentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "HorizontalChildAlignment",
            typeof(HorizontalAlignment),
            typeof(AspectRatioDecorator),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                    HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange),
            ValidateHorizontalChildAlignment);

    static bool ValidateHorizontalChildAlignment(object value)
    {
        if (!(value is HorizontalAlignment))
            return false;

        var horizontalAlignment = (HorizontalAlignment)value;
        return horizontalAlignment != HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
    }
    #endregion

    #region dp VerticalAlignment VerticalChildAlignment
    public VerticalAlignment VerticalChildAlignment
    {
        get { return (VerticalAlignment)GetValue(VerticalChildAlignmentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(VerticalChildAlignmentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty VerticalChildAlignmentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "VerticalChildAlignment",
            typeof(VerticalAlignment),
            typeof(AspectRatioDecorator),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                    VerticalAlignment.Top,
                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange),
            ValidateVerticalChildAlignment);

    static bool ValidateVerticalChildAlignment(object value)
    {
        if (!(value is VerticalAlignment))
            return false;

        var verticalAlignment = (VerticalAlignment)value;
        return verticalAlignment != VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
    }
    #endregion

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        if (Child == null) // we have no child, so we need no space
            return new Size(0, 0);

        constraint = SizeToRatio(constraint, false);
        Child.Measure(constraint);

        if (double.IsInfinity(constraint.Width) || double.IsInfinity(constraint.Height))
            return SizeToRatio(Child.DesiredSize, true);

        return constraint;
    }

    public Size SizeToRatio(Size size, bool expand)
    {
        double ratio = AspectRatio;

        double height = size.Width / ratio;
        double width = size.Height * ratio;

        if (expand)
        {
            width = Math.Max(width, size.Width);
            height = Math.Max(height, size.Height);
        }
        else
        {
            width = Math.Min(width, size.Width);
            height = Math.Min(height, size.Height);
        }

        return new Size(width, height);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        if (Child == null)
            return arrangeSize;

        var constrainedSize = arrangeSize;

        var fwChild = Child as FrameworkElement;
        if (fwChild != null)
        {
            constrainedSize.Height = Math.Min(constrainedSize.Height, fwChild.MaxHeight);
            constrainedSize.Width = Math.Min(constrainedSize.Width, fwChild.MaxWidth);
        }

        var newSize = SizeToRatio(constrainedSize, false);

        double widthDelta = arrangeSize.Width - newSize.Width;
        double heightDelta = arrangeSize.Height - newSize.Height;

        double top = 0;
        double left = 0;

        if (!double.IsNaN(widthDelta) && !double.IsInfinity(widthDelta))
            switch (HorizontalChildAlignment)
            {
                case HorizontalAlignment.Left:
                    break;
                case HorizontalAlignment.Center:
                    left = widthDelta / 2;
                    break;
                case HorizontalAlignment.Right:
                    left = widthDelta;
                    break;
            };

        if (!double.IsNaN(heightDelta) && !double.IsInfinity(heightDelta))
            switch (VerticalChildAlignment)
            {
                case VerticalAlignment.Top:
                    break;
                case VerticalAlignment.Center:
                    top = heightDelta / 2;
                    break;
                case VerticalAlignment.Bottom:
                    top = heightDelta;
                    break;
            };

        var finalRect = new Rect(new Point(left, top), newSize);
        Child.Arrange(finalRect);

        return arrangeSize;
    }
}
```

Кроме того, чтобы забиндить размер без особенных трюков, нам нужен скалирующий `IValueConverter`.

```
class ScalingConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
            object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null || parameter == null) // поддержка редактора WPF
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
        double v = (double)value;
        double p = (double)parameter;
        return v * p;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(
            object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Ну и для того, чтобы нормально передавать параметры в конвертер, сделаем типизирующий markup extension:

```
public class DoubleExtension : TypedValueExtension<double>
{
    public DoubleExtension(double value) : base(value) { }
}

public class TypedValueExtension<T> : MarkupExtension
{
    public TypedValueExtension(T value) { Value = value; }
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider sp) { return Value; }
}
```

Теперь можно написать так:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <src:ScalingConverter x:Key="Scaler"/>
</Window.Resources>
<src:AspectRatioDecorator AspectRatio="1"
                          VerticalChildAlignment="Center" HorizontalChildAlignment="Center">
    <!-- нам нужен радиус, запомним его куда-нибудь 
         например в тэг -->
    <Canvas Background="Beige" Name="Arena"
            Tag="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=Arena, Converter={StaticResource Scaler}, ConverterParameter={src:Double 0.5}}">
        <Path Fill="Pink">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathGeometry.Figures>
                        M 0,-1 A 1,1 30 0 1 0.5,-0.86602 L 0.25,-0.43301 A 0.5,0.5 30 0 0 0,-0.5 z
                    </PathGeometry.Figures>
                    <PathGeometry.Transform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <!-- и воспользуемся: -->
                            <TranslateTransform X="{Binding Tag, ElementName=Arena}" Y="{Binding Tag, ElementName=Arena}"/>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="0"
                                             CenterX="{Binding Tag, ElementName=Arena}" CenterY="{Binding Tag, ElementName=Arena}"/>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding Tag, ElementName=Arena}" ScaleY="{Binding Tag, ElementName=Arena}"
                                            CenterX="{Binding Tag, ElementName=Arena}" CenterY="{Binding Tag, ElementName=Arena}"/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </PathGeometry.Transform>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <Path Fill="Bisque">
            <Path.Data>
                <PathGeometry>
                    <PathGeometry.Figures>
                        M 0,-1 A 1,1 30 0 1 0.5,-0.86602 L 0.25,-0.43301 A 0.5,0.5 30 0 0 0,-0.5 z
                    </PathGeometry.Figures>
                    <PathGeometry.Transform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <TranslateTransform X="{Binding Tag, ElementName=Arena}" Y="{Binding Tag, ElementName=Arena}"/>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="30"
                                             CenterX="{Binding Tag, ElementName=Arena}" CenterY="{Binding Tag, ElementName=Arena}"/>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding Tag, ElementName=Arena}" ScaleY="{Binding Tag, ElementName=Arena}"
                                            CenterX="{Binding Tag, ElementName=Arena}" CenterY="{Binding Tag, ElementName=Arena}"/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </PathGeometry.Transform>
                </PathGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
        <src:CenteringNoClipper>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Привет"/>
            <src:CenteringNoClipper.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-15"/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="{Binding Tag, ElementName=Arena, Converter={StaticResource Scaler}, ConverterParameter={src:Double -0.75}}"/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="15"/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="{Binding Tag, ElementName=Arena}" Y="{Binding Tag, ElementName=Arena}"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </src:CenteringNoClipper.RenderTransform>
        </src:CenteringNoClipper>
        <src:CenteringNoClipper>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="мир!"/>
            <src:CenteringNoClipper.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-45"/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="{Binding Tag, ElementName=Arena, Converter={StaticResource Scaler}, ConverterParameter={src:Double -0.75}}"/>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="45"/>
                    <TranslateTransform X="{Binding Tag, ElementName=Arena}" Y="{Binding Tag, ElementName=Arena}"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </src:CenteringNoClipper.RenderTransform>
        </src:CenteringNoClipper>
    </Canvas>
</src:AspectRatioDecorator>
```

Получаем следующую картинку:

[image: окончательный вариант]

Разбиение на `UserControl`'ы сделаете сами, хорошо?

Comment: Идея с декоратором мне нравится. Буду ждать продолжения, интересно как ты сможешь уйти от жестких габаритов.

Comment: @Nodon: Хе-хе :) Это просто как раз. Допишу через пару часов.

Comment: Ты кстати планируешь отойти только от конкретного размера в пикселях или и от жестко заданного угла сегмента?

Comment: @Nodon: Пока только от размера в пикселях. Угол по идее тоже не проблема, но не хочу засорять код.

Comment: На счет масштабирования. Ты сделал геометрию в диапазоне [0,1]. Далее ты ее от масштабировал по размеру доступного пространства. Можно коэффициент забиндить к размеру, но это подойдет только в случае, если ширина и высота равны, иначе будет не круг, а овал. Я для решения этой проблемы в CodeBehind смотрю что меньше ширина или высота и использую ее для масштабирования.

Comment: @Nodon: Готово, смотри.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31103/discussion-between-nodon-and-vladd).

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, решил ли автор свою проблему, предложу вариант по которому пошёл бы я:

- Запускаем Blend for Visual Studio (Если нет бленды-процесс создания
  необходимого контрола несколько усложнится). В качестве проекта
  выбираем "WpfControlLibrary". Студия создаёт проект и открывает нам
  пустую форму пользовательского контрола.
- Сейчас по умолчанию корневой элемент на    нашем контроле-грид.
  Упаковываем его в Viewbox (он нужен для  пропорционального
  масштабирования элемента ) и задаём нашему контролу фиксированный
  размер.  Размечаем в гриде область где должны       находится
  визуальные части нашего контрола и    кидаем на эти области
  Image'ы и в качестве изображений ставим им    нужные нам на данных
  местах эскизы элементов контрола (Данную    процедуру можно
  пропустить-нужно исключительно для удобства отрисовки    )
- Выбираем нужные нам примитивы (Path, Rectangle, Ellipce и т.п) и
  обрисовываем ими наши эскизы. Далее можно сгруппировать несколько
  элементов в один (если например они логически являются одним
  элементом который должен реагировать на некоторые события (клик мыши
  например))
- Добавляем на форму прочие элементы управления: TextBlock'и для
  отображения информации (цифры, подписи ) и т.п.
- На этом процесс создания внешнего вида элемента управления фактически
  завершён. Чтобы он был интерактивным и настраиваемым (цвет отдельных
  элементов, события клика мыши, отображение каких-либо данных и т.п.)
  создать нашему контролу соответствующие свойства, методы и события и
  сделать привязку к ним у интерактивных элементов нашего контрола и
  т.д. и т.п. (в общем тут чистой воды создание пользовательского
  контрола. Мануалов по данному вопросу много, расписывать не буду )
- В рабочем проекте добавляем наш контрол на панель элементов и кидаем 
  его на форму и пользуемся =) Если чего-то не хватает - возвращаемся к 
  процессу редактирования свойств и поведения нашего контрола

Если Blend'а нет-создаём шаблон пользовательского элемента в студии. Операции тут идентичны описаным выше, за исключением того, что обрисовывать Path'aми эскизы придётся указывая координаты в поле "Data" элемента Path. Это весьма трудоёмкий процесс...

Comment: Ну я ее в общем решил, но по тупому при помощи ItemsControl + Code behind. Как все сделано мне вовсе не нравится.

Comment: Правда я совсем не пойму на кой черт мне использовать Grid. Тут Canvas и что бы отрисовать нужный элемент в нужном месте уже TranslateTransform и RotateTransform. И расчет размеров секций мне надо делать либо где-то в коде, либо ограничиться одним количеством сегментов и забить в xaml уже готовые числа.

Comment: Ну грид тут не обязателен. Но какой-то корневой элемент нужен грид как по мне самый удобный. Если размер секций меняется пропорционально размеру экрана то всё содержимое шаблона элемента управления помещается внутрь ViewBox + задаётся фиксированный размер элементов. Далее при масштабировании элемента ViewBox сам всё пропорционально растянет. Только надо не забыть проставить свойство  Stretch="Uniform" у ViewBox'а

Comment: Вот только в чем минус ViewBox. Он масштабирует сразу все фигуры, что приводит к масштабированию еще и толщины линий. Тут надо подбирать золотую середину по изначальному размеру. У меня сейчас все элементы заданы в размере [0;1] и потом они масштабируются выданным контролу размером. У путей масштабируется их геометрия. Если вместо моего масштабирования поставить ViewBox, то я буду видеть только очень толстые линии.