# Квадратные ячейки Grid

Tags: c#, wpf

Как сделать чтобы ячейки Grid были всегда квадратные?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Немного другое идеологически решение — декоратор, размер которого не ограничен, но который заставляет свой дочерний элемент сохранять нужную пропорцию сторон.

Код украден [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/463597/10105).

```
public class AspectRatioDecorator : Decorator
{
    #region dp double AspectRatio with validator ValidateAspectRatio
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AspectRatioProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "AspectRatio",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(AspectRatioDecorator),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                    1.0,
                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure),
            ValidateAspectRatio);

    public double AspectRatio
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(AspectRatioProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AspectRatioProperty, value); }
    }

    static bool ValidateAspectRatio(object value)
    {
        if (!(value is double))
            return false;

        var aspectRatio = (double)value;
        return aspectRatio > 0 &&
               !double.IsInfinity(aspectRatio) &&
               !double.IsNaN(aspectRatio);
    }
    #endregion

    #region dp HorizontalAlignment HorizontalChildAlignment
    public HorizontalAlignment HorizontalChildAlignment
    {
        get { return (HorizontalAlignment)GetValue(HorizontalChildAlignmentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HorizontalChildAlignmentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HorizontalChildAlignmentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "HorizontalChildAlignment",
            typeof(HorizontalAlignment),
            typeof(AspectRatioDecorator),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                    HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange),
            ValidateHorizontalChildAlignment);

    static bool ValidateHorizontalChildAlignment(object value)
    {
        if (!(value is HorizontalAlignment))
            return false;

        var horizontalAlignment = (HorizontalAlignment)value;
        return horizontalAlignment != HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
    }
    #endregion

    #region dp VerticalAlignment VerticalChildAlignment
    public VerticalAlignment VerticalChildAlignment
    {
        get { return (VerticalAlignment)GetValue(VerticalChildAlignmentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(VerticalChildAlignmentProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty VerticalChildAlignmentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "VerticalChildAlignment",
            typeof(VerticalAlignment),
            typeof(AspectRatioDecorator),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                    VerticalAlignment.Top,
                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsArrange),
            ValidateVerticalChildAlignment);

    static bool ValidateVerticalChildAlignment(object value)
    {
        if (!(value is VerticalAlignment))
            return false;

        var verticalAlignment = (VerticalAlignment)value;
        return verticalAlignment != VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
    }
    #endregion

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        if (Child == null) // we have no child, so we need no space
            return new Size(0, 0);

        constraint = SizeToRatio(constraint, false);
        Child.Measure(constraint);

        if (double.IsInfinity(constraint.Width) || double.IsInfinity(constraint.Height))
            return SizeToRatio(Child.DesiredSize, true);

        return constraint;
    }

    public Size SizeToRatio(Size size, bool expand)
    {
        double ratio = AspectRatio;

        double height = size.Width / ratio;
        double width = size.Height * ratio;

        if (expand)
        {
            width = Math.Max(width, size.Width);
            height = Math.Max(height, size.Height);
        }
        else
        {
            width = Math.Min(width, size.Width);
            height = Math.Min(height, size.Height);
        }

        return new Size(width, height);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size arrangeSize)
    {
        if (Child == null)
            return arrangeSize;

        var constrainedSize = arrangeSize;

        var fwChild = Child as FrameworkElement;
        if (fwChild != null)
        {
            constrainedSize.Height = Math.Min(constrainedSize.Height, fwChild.MaxHeight);
            constrainedSize.Width = Math.Min(constrainedSize.Width, fwChild.MaxWidth);
        }

        var newSize = SizeToRatio(constrainedSize, false);

        double widthDelta = arrangeSize.Width - newSize.Width;
        double heightDelta = arrangeSize.Height - newSize.Height;

        double top = 0;
        double left = 0;

        if (!double.IsNaN(widthDelta) && !double.IsInfinity(widthDelta))
            switch (HorizontalChildAlignment)
            {
                case HorizontalAlignment.Left:
                    break;
                case HorizontalAlignment.Center:
                    left = widthDelta / 2;
                    break;
                case HorizontalAlignment.Right:
                    left = widthDelta;
                    break;
            };

        if (!double.IsNaN(heightDelta) && !double.IsInfinity(heightDelta))
            switch (VerticalChildAlignment)
            {
                case VerticalAlignment.Top:
                    break;
                case VerticalAlignment.Center:
                    top = heightDelta / 2;
                    break;
                case VerticalAlignment.Bottom:
                    top = heightDelta;
                    break;
            };

        var finalRect = new Rect(new Point(left, top), newSize);
        Child.Arrange(finalRect);

        return arrangeSize;
    }
}
```

Имея это, можно писать что-то такое

```
<Window x:Class="AspectRatioDecoratorTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AspectRatioDecoratorTest"
        Title="Aspect ratio decorator test" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Background="Beige">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <local:AspectRatioDecorator AspectRatio="{Binding Value, ElementName=RatioSlider}"
                                    VerticalChildAlignment="Center">
            <Border Background="LightCoral"/>
        </local:AspectRatioDecorator>
        <Slider Grid.Row="1" Minimum="0.333333" Maximum="3" Value="1" Name="RatioSlider"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

И получать результат:

[image: раз]
[image: два]
[image: три]

Comment: Интересный подход. Спасибо!

Comment: @Lightness: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 6):

```
Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=ActualHeight}"
```